# probability random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

An urn contains $90$ marbles, of which there are $20$ green, $20$ black and $50$ red marbles. Tom draw marbles without replacement until the $6$th green marble. Let $X = \#$ of marbles drawn. Example : $GGGBRBGGBRG$ with $X = 11$

1. Find $\text{E}(X)$
2. Find $\text{Var}(X)$

I know that the range of $X$ is $\{ 6, ....,76\}$. At the $x$th draw, you get $6$th green meaning that

a. at $(x-1)$-th draw, you get $5$ green and

b. $x$-th you get $1$ out of $15$ green ball

So how can I find probability of $P(X=x)$ so that I can find $\text{E}(X)$ and $\text{Var}(X)$.

Comment: We use hypergeometric pmf to help. You got $20$ green and $70$ non-green initially. Following your argument, the probability of getting $5$ green in the first $(x - 1)$ draw is $\displaystyle \frac {\displaystyle \binom {20} {5} \binom {70} {x - 1 - 5}} {\displaystyle \binom {90} {x - 1}}$ and getting the $6$th green from the remaining $20 - 5$ green and $70 - x + 1 + 5$ non-green is $\displaystyle \frac {\displaystyle \binom {15} {1} \binom {76 - x} {0}} {\displaystyle \binom {91 - x} {1}} = \frac {15} {91 - x}$. Multiply them together you got the pmf.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that Tom keeps on drawing marbles until the urn is empty
and gives the first drawn marble number $1$, the second drawn marble
number $2$, et cetera. To make things more general assume that there
are $m$ marbles in total of which $g$ are green. Define $X_{1},\dots,X_{g}$
where $X_{i}$ denotes the number of the $i$-th drawn marble. In
this answer we will find $\mathsf{E}X_{r}$ and $\mathsf{Var}X_{r}$
for some $r\in\left\{ 1,\dots,g\right\} $. In your case we have $g=20$,
$m=90$ and $r=6$. Define: $$Y_{i}=\begin{cases}
X_{1}-1 & \text{if }i=0\\
X_{i+1}-X_{i}-1 & \text{if }0<i<g\\
m-X_{g} & \text{if }i=g
\end{cases}$$Observe that $Y_{0}$ is the number of non-green marbles drawn before
the first green marble was drawn, that $Y_{i}$ is the number of non-green
marbles drawn after the $i-1$-th green marble and before the $i$-th
green marble, and that $Y_{g}$ is the number of non-green marbles
drawn after the last drawn green marble.

Essential is that $Y_{0},Y_{1},\dots,Y_{g}$ by symmetry have identical
distribution, and secondly that $\mathsf{Cov}\left(Y_{i},Y_{j}\right)=\mathsf{Cov}\left(Y_{0},Y_{1}\right)$
if $i\neq j$. Let us denote the expectation of this distribution
by $\mu$, its variance by $\sigma^{2}$ and $\mathsf{Cov}\left(Y_{0},Y_{1}\right)$
by $c$.

It is evident that $m=g+\sum_{i=0}^{g}Y_{i}$ so that $m=g+\left(g+1\right)\mu$.

So we found an expression for the expectation: $$\mu=\frac{m-g}{g+1}$$

Also it is evident that $X_{r}=r+\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}Y_{i}$ and consequently:
$$\mathsf{E}X_{r}=r+r\mu=r+\frac{r\left(m-g\right)}{g+1}=\frac{r\left(m+1\right)}{g+1}\text{ for }r\in\left\{ 1,\dots,g\right\}$$

This is our first result and it is acquainted purely on base of the
fact that the $Y_{i}$ have identical distribution.

On base of $m=g+\sum_{i=0}^{g}Y_{i}$ we conclude that $0=\mathsf{Var}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{g}Y_{i}\right)=\left(g+1\right)\sigma^{2}+\left(g+1\right)gc=\left(g+1\right)\left(\sigma^{2}+gc\right)$
and consequently that: $$\sigma^{2}+gc=0$$

Further we have: $$\mathsf{Var}X_{r}=\mathsf{Var}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}Y_{i}\right)=r\sigma^{2}+r\left(r-1\right)c=-rgc+r\left(r-1\right)c=r\left[r-g-1\right]c$$

What remains is finding $c$ and need the distribution of $\left(Y_{0},Y_{1}\right)$
for that: $$\mathsf{P}\left(Y_{0}=i\wedge Y_{1}=j\right)=\binom{m}{g}^{-1}\binom{m-i-j-2}{g-2}$$
where $i,j$ are nonnegative integers that satisfy $i+j\leq m-g$.

We find $\mathbb{E}Y_{0}Y_{1}=\binom{m}{g}^{-1}\sum_{i+j+k=m-2}\binom{k}{g-2}\binom{i}{1}\binom{j}{1}=\binom{m}{g}^{-1}\binom{m}{g+2}=\frac{\left(m-g-1\right)\left(m-g\right)}{\left(g+1\right)\left(g+2\right)}$

Then $$c=\mathbb{E}Y_{0}Y_{1}-\mu^{2}=\frac{\left(m-g-1\right)\left(m-g\right)}{\left(g+1\right)\left(g+2\right)}-\left(\frac{m-g}{g+1}\right)^{2}=-\frac{\left(m-g\right)\left(m+1\right)}{\left(g+1\right)^{2}\left(g+2\right)}$$

So that $$\mathsf{Var}X_{r}=\frac{r\left(g-r+1\right)\left(m-g\right)\left(m+1\right)}{\left(g+1\right)^{2}\left(g+2\right)}$$

---

I hope that I didn't make any mistakes and that there is a better way to find this.